# sqlMapConfig file not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ibatis

[image]Am facing weird issue while trying to launch my web application

```
Could not find resource sqlMapConfig.xml
```

my project use maven with an embedded Tomcat :
i did try to add the file under class path , i did try to add
the sqlMapConfig.xml file into `Resources` but that didnt work..
what is weird that if i try to do `maven update project` from eclipse and try to launch the application from the eclipse sometimes the project found the config file but that is not always the case , I need to build the package and launch the jar by using maven and cmd....
below a screen shot of my code 
[image: eclipse hierarchy]

[main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF54Z.png)

[image: initialize the sqlmap Sqlconfig is under db package]

Answer (score 0):

Put it back into `/resources` and do:

```
String resource = "classpath:sqlMapConfig.xml"
```

Comment: i did and i still have the same error  i will add a new screen shot so if the is any missing link could help thx anw

Answer (score 0):

I did figure it out my problem but still not understanding why maybe cause of my lack of maven experience :

all i had to do was just `update maven project` from eclipse then do the `mvn package` from cmd it seems that `mvn compile` were corrupting my files but as i was saying that i have no clue why yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here  `/` before config file and put this file in resources folder

```
private static String path= "/sqlmap-config.xml";

public static SqlMapClient getSqlMapInstance() throws IOException {
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(path);
        sqlMapClient = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);

        return sqlMapClient;

    }
```

NOTE: make sure your `sqlmap-config.xml` is located in classpath `resoures` folder.